# The logic of if statement and (return redirect) in django

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-views, logic

```
def set_default(request, id):
    Address.objects.filter(customer=request.user, default=True).update(default=False)
    Address.objects.filter(pk=id, customer=request.user).update(default=True)

    previous_url = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER")

    if "delivery_address" in previous_url:
        return redirect("checkout:delivery_address")

    return redirect("account:addresses")
```

This is a function that sets address to default and if the user came from checkout address page it sets default and return to same page.My question is about the logic of the if statment here.As far as I understand..If the condition is true

```
return redirect("checkout:delivery_address")
```

will be executed and it will exit the if condition then the last line will be executed

```
return redirect("account:addresses")
```

Why doesn't that happen and only the statment after if is executed when the condition is true?

Comment: If I understand you correct you expect both redirects to happen? a return will exit the function, nothing after it will be executed if it is reached.

Comment: My assumption is that `if` statement **isn't** actually being hit, because you can only have 1 redirect as a response. try printing out previous_url, and i'm going to guess `"delivery_address"` won't be the the url

Comment: one function cant have multiple returns unless its separated from conditions. whenever your `if is true`  it will `return redirect("checkout:delivery_address")` this and then it won't go further. and when `if is false` the last line will get executed.